# Dictionary creation problems

Tags: python, dictionary

I am enumerating from a list called master. The list is a list of lists.

I enumerate through master to get:

> index ---> sub_list(containing items)

I then enumerate through the sublists to get the items:

> index of sublist items ---> items of sub_list

I am trying to create a dictionary of `{index of sublist items:items of sub_list}`
by putting the keys and the values into separate lists and then zipping them together. If I print these lists I am seeing all the values I want, however when I try to zip them into a dictionary, it adds only a few of the values I want. I really don't know what's happening.

```
def category_index_from_title(category_title):
    return master[0].index(category_title)

master = list(iter_rows(Millar_sheet))

for row, values in enumerate(master[1:]): 
    for index, client_values in enumerate(values): 
        category_name.append(str(category_title_from_index(index)))
        category_value.append(str(client_values))

dictionary = dict(zip(category_name, category_value))
```

Comment: Items with the same index will not all make it into the `dict`; just one. No duplicate keys allowed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks Moses, I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Nothing to worry about, Jimbo. This is a good practical lesson in understanding how a dictionary works (admittedly, the *hard* way; but now it's unlikely you'll ever fall for this again).